# how do I send 'put' request through javaScript & Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax, google-sheets

I have to write to my spreadsheet programatically. It allows my to write to a particular cell of the spreadsheet. My code is :

```
function update(){
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: 'PUT',
                    contentType: "application/atom+xml",
                    url: "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/0Aq69FHX3TV4ndDBDVFFETUFhamc5S25rdkNoRkd4WXc/od6/private/full/R2C1",
                    dataType: "xml",
                    data: "new.xml",
                    success: function() {
                        alert('Put Success');
                    },
                    error: function(a,b,c) {
                        console.log("XMLHttpRequest: " + a);
                        console.log("textStatus: " + b);
                        console.log("errorThrown: " + c);
                        alert("XMLHttpRequest : " + a + " textStatus : " + b + " errorThrown : " + c);
                    }
                });
            }
```

I can write to spreadsheet using xml element only. So, I have created (new.xml):

```
<entry>
    <id>https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/0Aq69FHX3TV4ndDBDVFFETUFhamc5S25rdkNoRkd4WXc/od6/private/full/R2C1</id>
    <link rel="edit" type="application/atom+xml"
    href="https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/0Aq69FHX3TV4ndDBDVFFETUFhamc5S25rdkNoRkd4WXc/worksheetId/private/full/R2C1"/>
    <gs:cell row="2" col="1" inputValue="300"/>
</entry>
```

But, my code it is still throwing an error. I think it is related to the XML file I am writing. I think, creating new.xml is my error. Please suggest how to write back? How do I create an xml element ?

For referece : [Update Cells](http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/data/3.0/developers_guide.html#UpdatingCells)

Output : 
a :
[object Object]

b :
undefined

c :

Comment: It might help if you told us what the error was! I suspect, however, that the problem is that you are trying to PUT a string consisting of a filename and not XML (i.e. `data: 'new.xml'` should be `data: '<entry><id>etc etc`.

Comment: data : '<entry> ...' is not proper string & gives error. Let me add what the error in previous case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to [same origin policy restriction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) you cannot send AJAX requests cross domain. Here you are trying to send an AJAX request to `https://spreadsheets.google.com` and unless your site is hosted on `https://google.com` this won't work. To try to workaround this restriction you could write a server script on your server which will serve as a bridge between your domain and google.com. Then you could send the AJAX request to your script which will delegate.

Comment: But it is given in the Google Documentation ! It is not on my site. It is on Google Doc only that I am accessing using my Gmail. Either what another way / solution ?

Comment: @Sarang, could you point to where this code is given in the documentation?

Comment: I am not saying about code, it is said to do like this... Have a look to output !

Comment: @Sarang, yes but you cannot send AJAX requests cross domain and that's for security reasons. Browsers simply won't let you do it.

Comment: Ok got it ! Well, I am developing iGoogle Gadget. It is compulsory for me to use JavaScript only ! :( Any solution ?

Comment: @Sarang, I've detailed a workaround in my answer: you could write a server side script on your domain and then send AJAX request to it. If you only need a pure javascript solution then I am afraid that this is impossible.