# jquery.ajax() not working

Tags: jquery, xml, parsing, post

I am trying to fetch xml file using jquery.post() method. My code is :

```
function getTitle()
            {
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full.txt",
                    dataType: "xml",
                    success: function(xml) {
                        var i=0;
                        $(xml).find('entry').each(function(){
                            if($(this).find('title').text().toString() == "Sample Spreadsheet"){
                                var href = $(this).find('link')[1].getAttribute('href').toString();
                                var url="https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/" + href.split('=')[1] + "/private/full";
                                alert(href.split('=')[1]);
                            }
                            i++;
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
```

But, it is not giving me alert ! How do I solve ?

Comment: [Your URL is 404](https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full.txt)

Comment: It does not work for the same reason given in your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667577/how-do-i-send-put-request-through-javascript-ajax). And btw. you are not even using `$_post` here (or anything POSTish)).

Comment: ohk Felix ! thanks a lot to all !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AJAX `same origin policy` does not allow a request like this. Only way to request data from another domain is to use JSON-Padding.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: Any link regarding how do I implement it ?

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion is that you download a tool that allows you to view http data.
A good free tool for this is [Fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com/fiddler2/version.asp).
It will vastly improve your ability to debug this type of problem.